# What Gamma does Cycles render when rendering an EXR?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, .exr

I’m wondering (for precise compositing), what gamma does Cycles render when rendering out an EXR (with view transform set to Filmic)?

Comment: I am not sure what gamma it uses in detail, but you can import the filmic ocio into your compositor and convert the footage. Or just directly render in ACES. Here are some examples
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJYVIKjYkO8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7FWNNDXBl0